# netbeans how is it organized

Tags: netbeans, jar

i have a running package consisting of classes all written by myself, except of course for some basic java libraries. The reason is simple : everytime i try to import an external jar to use it instead of writing it myself, netbeans fails to find the files, so it simply does not work.

as you will understand, i'm really not happy with this situation, so i looked for a solution and tried everything to get external files being integrated in my package ...

So my question : does anyone  know a site with a simple and clear explanation on how netbeans deals with the different files, and where they should be stored ? I've read all questions and answers about importing external jar files, but nothing helps ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an external library:

1. Open the project properties
2. Click on libraries
3. Click on "Add JAR/Folder"
4. Select the jar file(s) in question

If a library consists of multiple jar files and you want to use that in multiple projects:

1. Open "Tools -> Libraries"
2. Click "New Library"
3. Add the jar files using the "Add JAR/Folder" button
4. Close the "Ant Library Manager" window
5. Open the project properties
6. Click on "libraries"
7. Add the global library by clicking on the "Add Library button"

The NetBeans manual has a lot of information on how to use the IDE: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/toc.htm

The chapter "Managing the classpath" describes how to manage external libraries:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/create_japps.htm#CHDFBFAD

The chapter "Creating Dependencies Between Projects" describes how you can re-use code from one project in another:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/create_japps.htm#CHDIBBEB

Comment: Thanks for your clear post but again, all i try, nothing seems to work. Using an external library, he doesn't find him. Creating a global library, can't add it to the project as it doesn't show up in the list ...

Comment: @Veronique: this works for me. I do it on a daily basis. I guess there is something you are not telling us.